# After migrating a WP site, changes made in the Customizer don't appear on the new site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress site, built using the Hestia theme, on my local PC. I'd like to push the full site, exactly as everything looks locally, to production. I'm able to migrate the codebase, database, plugins, base theme, etc. using [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to prod.

The problem I have is that I did a variety of customizing to the theme in the WYSIWYG theme editor in Wordpress (the customizer) on my local PC and those updates aren't coming through to production with any type of import that I do (I've tried the duplicator and the Wordpress import tool).

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong in the process? How do I get that customized theme / site to production looking exactly like it does on my local PC? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicator does exactly as its name suggests - duplicates everything from the local site - so there should be no difference. By "WYSIWYG theme editor" I assume you mean the Customiser, but either way any changes made in WP will be saved to the database (which gets copied using Duplicator) or directly in the files (if you are using Appearance/Editor). Can you some specific examples so we may be able to suggest where the problem is?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for the reply! Yes, I mean the Customiser. The example is basically that I use the Duplicator, and everything goes to the production site. All pages are there, all posts, plugins, etc. I then activate all of the plugins and the theme. The problem is, after the theme is activated, it just shows the standard layout that comes with the theme - there is none of the customization I did on the local site. I'm wondering why that's happening and how to get it to appear.

Comment: I always use Duplicator for moving sites and never had a problem, although I've never tried it with a site that used the Customiser. But I don't see why the changes don't appear on the new site, because they had to be saved either in the db or the files, both of which are copied! When you built the package, did you exclude anything at all from the build? Also, I'm going to edit your title to make it clearer what the question is, as someone may have direct experience with the issue.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I don't believe I excluded anything from the build, no. And it weird, for all of the reasons you said, it totally should be working! That's why I'm so confused :)

Comment: I never use the Customiser so I don't know its quirks, so I'm afraid that's as far as I can help - sorry! Hopefully someone else might have seen this happen & be able to help.

Comment: I don't know why this issue occurs but I managed to fix it with this before https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/

Comment: @I haz kode Oh man, that looks like exactly what I need. I'll give it a try tonight. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're most welcome. Hope everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

The customizer contents are saved in the database AFAIK.

There is a plugin for export/umport of customizer data: https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/

Comment: Thanks @johannes! Unfortunately, it's not as simple as just a select all and copy because there are lots of sub-elements that were chosen within the customizer like pages that will show up on the nav, images to use, text of different subsections. A manual copy like that would take quite a bit of time, which I'd ideally like to avoid.

Comment: This could totally be that I just did something incorrectly in the migration with the Duplicator so I'll try that again as people are saying all of that info should be in the database. Just curious if anyone knows anything special I need to do or steps I may have missed to make sure contents from the customizer get pushed to prod.

Comment: You could try the plugin I linked to in my changed answer

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue and just got done banging my head against the wall, so I figured I'd share.  My particular theme was Blocksy (though it sounds like your issue may be imilar).

It turns out that the theme settings were being stored in a **wp_options** entry named **theme_mods_blocksy-child**.  I confirmed that they existed in the new database after restoring from the backed up SQL.  However, as soon as I would visit the new WordPress installation, that entry was being deleted for some reason.  I still don't know *why* this was happening, but luckily the solution was simple in my case.  I created a backup of the theme settings here:

https://my_wordpress_site/wp-admin/customize.php

Exported the settings from: General Options > General > Manage Options

Then imported the backed up settings in the same fashion on the new installation.

It sounds from what I was reading that the [customizer export import plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/) would work well if your theme does not make this kind of import/export functionality readily available from the Customization screen like the theme I was using does.